# Can you derive histogram y-values from a Pandas plot call?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Let's say I am trying to plot ages as a histogram with density counts:

```
ax = inputs['Age'].plot(kind='hist', bins=10, range = (20,100), grid=True, density=True)
```

Is there a way I can get the y-values calculated from the density at each bin returned?

Or do I have to calculate them separately for each bin?

Comment: you could use matplotlib.pyplot.hist, which returns the bins and values

Comment: Thanks Arco Blast! Although it is strange it cannot be returned from the Pandas package itself, this definitely works.

Comment: `numpy.histogram` is also an option, though I agree with Arco Bast on advising you use `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` instead of `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

Comment: happy to hear that it works ... I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `pandas.Series.plot` does not return the bins, `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`does. Therefore, if you want to get the very same plot and the bins, you could use:

```
bins, values, _ = ax.hist(inputs['Age'], bins=10, range = (20,100), density = True)
ax.grid() # there is no grid=True option in matplotlib.pyplot.hist
```